# how to add custom styles dynamically in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to move an image according to mouse movement but it doesnt work the way it has to here's the code

I am trying to add myStyle class to elements.classList but it shows in classList , effects of style doesnt apply on the elements.

```
const [value, setvalue] = useState({x:null, y:null});


  const myStyle = {
    transform: `translateX(calc(-50% +${value.x}px)) translateY(calc(-50% +${value.y}px))`,

  }

  const element = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    let elements= element.current.children;
    console.log(elements)
    const updateMousePosition = ev => {
      setvalue({ x: ev.clientX, y: ev.clientY });
      let xValue = ev.clientX - window.innerWidth /2; 
      let yValue = ev.clientY - window.innerHeight /2;

      setvalue ({x:xValue , y:yValue})

      console.log(value.x , value.y)

      for(let i=1; i< 22; i++) {
        if(i == 19 || i== 20){ continue ; }
        elements[i].classList.add('myStyle')
        console.log(elements[i].classList)

        // elements[i].style.transform =`translateX(calc(-50% +${value.x}px)) translateY(calc(-50% +${value.y}px))`
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', updateMousePosition);
  
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', updateMousePosition);
      };
  }, [value]);
```

i also try to directly add style by transform method but it also shows error .

assume the div code be

```
<main ref={element}>
        <div className="vignette"></div>
        <div className="vignette"></div>
        <div className="vignette"></div>
      </main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code.

1. `myStyle` is a variable not a className. You should not add this name to the classList array, instead you should apply the style directly.
2. In `calc` function there should be space before and after the operation. So the code should be this:

```
 elements[i].style.transform = `translateX(calc(-50% + ${value.x}px)) translateY(calc(-50% + ${value.y}px))`;
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up it is solved now  but isn't how this classes are defined in react as variable to use it   
 and if you have any way to add style of myStyle to elements that would be helpful .

Comment: You're welcome. classNames should be defined in your css classes and unless they're not defined, you can't use them. There is a way to apply your myStyle variable like this:
`elements[i].style = { ...elements[i].style, ...myStyle }`.